# How can I add a bar chart based on user form input with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to add a bar chart based on the user's form input. After the form has been submitted, it should show the chart. Could any of you help me?

In the label I would like to show the name data. In the chart I would like to show a bar with MonthDays and Availablefordays.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const Multipleinput = () => {

const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
Name: "",
MonthDays: "",
Availablefordays: ""
});

const [records, SetRecords] = useState([]);

const handleInput = (e) => {
const name = e.target.name;
const value = e.target.value;

setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, [name]: value })
}

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const newRecord = { ...userInfo, id: new Date().getTime().toString() }

SetRecords([...records, newRecord]);

setUserInfo({ Name: "", MonthDays: "", Availablefordays: "" });
}

return (
 <div>
  <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
    <label htmlFor="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" value={userInfo.Name} onChange={handleInput}> 
 </input>
    <label htmlFor="MonthDays">Month Days</label>
    <input type="text" value={userInfo.MonthDays} onChange= 
 {handleInput}></input>
    <label htmlFor="Availablefordays">Available for days</label>
    <input type="text" value= 
 {userInfo.Availablefordays} onChange={handleInput}></input>
    <button type="submit" >Save User</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: `SetRecords` should be `setRecords` by convention

Comment: You can make use of chart.js or any other library for creating the bar chart.